# advantage of assigning events dynamically for static buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to Jquery and in many examples and codes , I see event handlers are assigned dynamically using Jquery ( $("#button").click(somefunction) ) for HTML components even though they are statically created.

Is there any advantage of binding events dynamically to buttons that are created statically ?
I can get the advantage if the components are created dynamically ? Can some one please explain me.

Comment: It keeps presentation and the logic separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantage you get is, it separate's business logic from markup.

Comment: and you can keep all the related events together making them easier to find/update.

Comment: but I can also achieve the same using onclick event of HTML attribute by supplying some javascript function which is defined in external js file.

Comment: Let's assume you are working on business logic and some body on markup. Do u like ur code getting effected due to markup changes?no right. That's the basic advantage of code seperation.

Comment: I suggest you to have alook at MVC architectural pattern.

Comment: got it. Thanks Venu Gopal. Will look into MVC architectural pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, and it has to do with code mainteinance and separation between HTML and JS.

Assigning all of the click events in one place means that:

1. your HTML will be cleaner and easier to read
2. when you will have to change something you will have all the code in one place making it much easier to find/modify things.

Of course, from a purely technical point of view, you can also add `onclick` events directly in the HTML, and it will work, but it is better practice to separate HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Some more are,

1. Externalizing the code will help page load fast. Provided you externalize it properly.
2. It creates a SEO friendly HTML page.
3. You can add more dynamic behavior using javaScript.